# Why is the Sine Curve changing through time?

Tags: processing

The code below plots an ellipse according to a sine curve.

The increment of i fits the size of the drawing and the angle increment should be periodic as it is a factor of 2*pi yet the curve seems to accelerate and change over time. Why is the curve not constant?

```java
float r = 3;
float the = 0;

void setup()
{    
  size( 1500, 300 );
  frameRate( 500 );
  smooth();
} 

void draw()
{
  translate( 0, height/2 );
  background(0);
  for ( int i=0; i<1500; i+=1 )
  {
     ellipse( i * 10, sin( the ) * 50, r, r );   
     the += ( 2 * PI ) / 150;
  }
}
```

Comment: Finite precision? Rounding errors?

Comment: thanks - where would this happen in the code? in Theta?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This definitely has to do with the precision of floating points, if you just mod `the` everytime by `TWO_PI`, the curve becomes almost constant with little to no movement. But you can still notice some dots moving 1 pixel or so quite often.

```java
float r = 3;
float the = 0;

void setup()
{    
  size( 1500, 300 );
  frameRate( 500 );
  smooth();
} 

void draw()
{
  translate( 0, height/2 );
  background(0);
  for ( int i=0; i<1500; i+=1 )
  {
     ellipse( i * 10, sin( the ) * 50, r, r );   
     the += ( 2 * PI ) / 150;
     the %= TWO_PI;
  }
}
```

Peter's answer also works, it achieves pretty much the same thing but by being more *specific and precise* setting it to zero instead of getting remainder from `TWO_PI`

#### Update:

As pointed out by Peter in the comments below, just to make your sketch a bit more efficient and cut down on the movement of points even more, you can reduce the for loop to iterate only upto 150 and move `the %= TWO_PI` out of the for loop :

```java
void setup()
{    
  size( 1500, 300 );
  frameRate( 500 );
  smooth();
} 

void draw()
{
  translate( 0, height/2 );
  background(0);
  for ( int i=0; i<150; i+=1 )
  {
    ellipse( i * 10, sin( the ) * 50, r, r );   
    the += ( 2 * PI ) / 150;
  }
  the %= TWO_PI;
}
```

Comment: Because whenever `the` overshoots value of `TWO_PI`, the mod operator returns the remainder of `VALUE_ABOVE_TWO_PI` divided by `TWO_PI` which works in a sense that whenever you reach `TWO_PI`, start counting from `0` again, but I think setting it explicitly to `0` after the for loop is the better choice here, like Peter did.

Comment: There is one good reason why your answer should be the accepted answer: You showed an alternative way and also pointed to mine. So everyone, who is interested, gets more background and would be able to make his/her own decision. I also learned from your example.  It is new for me that, the modulo operator can be used with floats. And there are two things I also remarked: The for loop does not need to iterate up to 1500; 150 is OK. And the line `the %= TWO_PI;` can then be positioned after the for loop.

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer Thank you very much for the feedback. About your remarks, yes the for loop can be cut down, good point. However, moving the line `the %= TWO_PI` out of the loop still works somewhat but the movement in the points increases to the extent where it is visible even if you do not focus too much, but that happens when the for loop iterates to 1500, when it does upto 150, there is almost no movement.

Comment: Yes, that what I meant (only iterate to 150 and then move the line after the loop). ( English is not my native language ;-) ).  When you iterate up to 1500 the `the` variable increases to 20 * PI and the X-coordinates reach values of 15000 which is outside of the display.

Answer (score 2):

The variable `the` is a float which you constantly increase in the *endless* draw loop. At  some point `the` flows over and starts with 0 (or something negative). From this point on the x and y coordinates  wont be in correlation. Then the graph beginns to flicker.

It would help if you intialize the `the`variable at the end of the draw loop.

```
float r = 3;
float the = 0;

void setup()
{    
  size( 1500, 300 );
  frameRate( 500 );
  smooth();
} 

void draw()
{
  translate( 0, height/2 );
  background(0);
  for ( int i=0; i<1500; i+=1 )
  {
     ellipse( i * 10, sin( the ) * 50, r, r );   
     the += ( 2 * PI ) / 150;
  }

  the = 0;
}
```